# @ImportResource not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mustache

I am new to Spring boot and I want to implement simple web application which renders UI using some Mustache templates.

I have written some Spring components (controllers,DAO,Services) whose package structure is different (not falling under same or sub directory as Spring boor runner class). So I am using `@ImportResource` annotation to declare spring configuration. But my application is not reading any configuration files.

Please refer below code snippet for more details

1. Project Structure :

[image]

Here not that, Spring boot application launcher classes written in package `SpringPropertyReaderApplication`.

`ApplicationConfiguration` class is written under same hierarchical package structure which defined few more configuration using `@ImportResource` annotation.

2. Spring boot application launcher class.

> package com.example.launcher;
>
> ```
> import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
> import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
>
> @SpringBootApplication
> public class SpringPropertyReaderApplication {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>
>       ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringPropertyReaderApplication.class, args);
>
>       System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
>       System.out.println("-----Printing Bean Definition Names ------------");
>       System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
>       for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
>           System.out.println(name);
>       }
>       System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
>       System.out.println("--------------------END------------------------");
>       System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
>   }
> }
> ```

3. ApplicationConfiguration class where I have shared location of other Spring configuration files.

> package com.example.launcher.configuration;
>
> ```
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
>
> @Configuration
> @ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:application-context.xml"})
> public class ApplicationConfiguration {
>
>   @Bean
>   public String someDummyBean1() {
>       return "someDummyBean1";
>   }
> }
> ```

4. Spring Application configuration which is not getting loaded by the container.

Here, I have added component scan annotation to scan my services and controllers which were not in the same package as Spring launcher class.

> ```
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
>
>
>   <context:component-scan
>       base-package="com.example" />
>
>   <bean id="xmlStringBean1" class="java.lang.String">
>       <constructor-arg value="stringBean1" />
>   </bean>
>
> </beans>
> ```

I have added code to log of all bean names which are loaded by Spring boot. But I did not find any bean with name "xmlStringBean1" and "myController".

Also note that, this application works fine If i put my Rest controller and other classes under the same package hierarchy as Spring boot launcher class.

Comment: Try this: @ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:spring/application-context.xml"}) . As your application-context.xml resides inside the spring directory not at the root.

Comment: It is uncommon these days to use XML configuration. Consider using java based config

Comment: @Himanshu, your suggestion helped me to fix the issue. I used the annotation @ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:spring/application-context.xml"}) and it started detecting the XML configuration files. Could you please add this as answer, so I will mark it as final solution.

Comment: @Himanshu, it was little tricky because if I was getting exception "File not found" is I provided a wrong file name which even does not exist in the class path. But I was not getting any exception with my old approach "@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:application-context.xml"})". So, I was  assuming that, container finds the file but its not loading the beans.

Comment: What if I don't want the spring beans file to be overwritten with every rebuild. How do I set the classpath used by @ImportResource so I can set it to a location that doesn't get overwritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, application-context.xml resides inside the spring folder under `src/main/resources`. But the @ImportResource annotation defined in `ApplicationConfiguration.java` tries to scan it just inside the root path. Hence, the file was not detected.

```
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:application-context.xml"})
```

to be replaced with

```
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:spring/application-context.xml"}) .
```

This will enforce framework to search for application-context.xml inside spring directory (starting from root level).

Comment: FYI to others landing here with a similar but different problem, `@Configuration` has to come before `@ImportResource` or any ${variables} inside will not resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I think your spring boot application is not detecting the class annotated with `@Configuration`*, because by default it will try to find the Configuration classes in the same or child packages as the main class*. Annotate your `SpringPropertyReaderApplication` with `@ComponentScan`, like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ApplicationConfiguration.class})
public class SpringPropertyReaderApplication {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I verified this case. Bean name "someDummyBean1" is getting printed in the logs. So its confirmed that "ApplicationConfiguration" class is detected and all its beans are created.